# Get values from dropdown menu's, run query and add values to formview c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I have a asp.net webform which contains a formView, 3 dropdown menus and a submit button. The dropdown menus get their values from the database.

When the user clicks the submit button values from the dropdown menus should be run through our query and display the outcome in the formView. This is not happening.

When we give standard values for other, meat and vegetables in the callSelectProduct() we can see the correct output in the form view, but this is on page load.

This is the click method from the submit button:

```
protected void getRecipe(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ddlOther = DropDownOther.SelectedValue;
        string ddlVegetables = DropDownVegetables.SelectedValue;
        string ddlMeat = DropDownMeat.SelectedValue;

        int ddlIntOther = int.Parse(ddlOther);
        int ddlIntVegetables = int.Parse(ddlVegetables);
        int ddlIntMeat = int.Parse(ddlMeat);

        Business.Class1.callSelectProduct(ddlIntOther, ddlIntMeat, ddlIntVegetables);
    }
```

This is callSelectProduct():
The Debug.WriteLine gives the good values back in the debug console, but then the page reloads because of the submit button click and then the Debug.WriteLine gives 0 0 0 back. I think that's why I don't see anything in the FormView. Because the combination of 0 0 0 will not return anything.

```
public static void callSelectProduct(int other, int meat, int vegetables)
    {
        SelectProduct(other, meat, vegetables);
    }


  [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethod(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
        public static Data.SouthWind.SelectRecipesFromIngredientsDataTable SelectProduct(int otherGet, int meatGet, int vegetablesGet)
        {
            int other = otherGet;
            int meat = meatGet;
            int vegetables = vegetablesGet;


            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is class 1 Other  " + other + " Vegetable " + vegetables + " Meat " + meat);
            DataAccess.SouthWindTableAdapters.SelectRecipesFromIngredientsTableAdapter tableAdaptertest = new DataAccess.SouthWindTableAdapters.SelectRecipesFromIngredientsTableAdapter();
            return tableAdaptertest.GetData(other, meat, vegetables);


        }
```

This is our webform:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:FormView ID="RecipeFormView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            RecipeName:
            <asp:TextBox ID="RecipeNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RecipeName") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            RecipeName:
            <asp:TextBox ID="RecipeNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RecipeName") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            RecipeName:
            <asp:Label ID="RecipeNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RecipeName") %>' />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="SelectProduct" TypeName="Business.Class1">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="otherGet" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="meatGet" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="vegetablesGet" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownOther" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" DataTextField="IngredientName" DataValueField="IngredientId">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownVegetables" runat="server" DataSourceID="SelectVegetables" DataTextField="IngredientName" DataValueField="IngredientId" Height="16px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownMeat" runat="server" DataSourceID="SelectMeat" DataTextField="IngredientName" DataValueField="IngredientId">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="SelectMeat" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="SelectMeat" TypeName="Business.Class1"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="SelectVegetables" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="SelectVegetables" TypeName="Business.Class1"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="SelectOther" TypeName="Business.Class1"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="getRecipe" Text="Button" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
    <br />

</div>
    </form>
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: It is not completely clear what is the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Post your exact issue you are experiencing with this code.

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it's a bit more clear now. Thanks for your reactions guys:)

Answer (score 0):

Are you use !IsPostBack in outer of you dropdown binding method in inside of pageload event ?

for

```
void page-load()
{
if(!IsPostBack)
{
//Call all dropdownlist binding method  
}

}
```